# Top 10 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Following a load test of my website I am trying to find the slowest performing web objects of my application. I have a field called 'path' with the applications object path along with a field called 'total_active' which gives the load time of the object. I have thousands of these records and I was wondering how I could just get the top 10 slowest along which what the objects slowest load time was.

I've tried the following, but it just gives me the objects in order of load time and doesnt group them. Can anyone advise?

```
select 
    path,
    time_active
from lb.object
order by time_active desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: What do you want them grouped by?

Comment: The top 10 slowest paths along with their slowest load time.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT path, sum(time_active) as summed FROM lb.object
group by path
order by summed desc limit 10
```

?

Comment: Yep that works, I changed it a little bit to use max(time_active) so I got the slowest load time. Thanks!

Comment: @user3323931 Use AVG() to get the slowest average load times and order by the top 10 of those. No point in skewing your performance 'issues' by one-off occurrences

Answer (score 0):

What is your group criteria.

the query you posted will do the the job you asked for.
if you want to to really group them have a look at:

**group by**. Try understanding
**having** 
and how it differs from 
**where**

[group by having](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

probably what you look for is:

```
select * from (select 
    path, max(time_active) as t
from
    lb.object
group by path) tab_1
 order by t desc
 limit 10;
```

- using the order by clause directly in the inner select will mess up the sorting

Comment: *"using the order by clause directly in the inner select will mess up the sorting"* No, that is wrong. It will not.

Comment: yeah. what you say is right. what I meant was that the sort should be done on max(time_active) and not on time_active. IF you are using alias that should be OK.
 Basically it's the same thing, only using alias is faster. Vote up for the first comment.